# filter_var_array и значение по умолчанию

Tags: php

Пишу на php 5.3. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, если использовать `filter_var_array()` и ключ в массиве отсутствует, функция добавляет его со значением `null`. Даже, если я задал значение по умолчанию. Это нормальное поведение? Мне бы вот хотелось как-нибудь не `null`, а значение по умолчанию.

Пример:

```
$input = array('internet' => true);

$args = array(       
    'internet' => array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, 
                        'flags' => FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE),
    'printed' => array('filter' => FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN, 
                       'flags' => FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE, 
                       'options' => array('default' => false))
    );
$result = filter_var_array($input, $args);
```

В выходе получаем `array('internet' => true, 'printed' => null)`

З.Ы. Обрабатываю данные пришедшие с формы в которой есть checkbox. Он всю малину и портит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читаем доки ([filter_var_array](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var-array.php)):

> > mixed filter_var_array ( array $data [, mixed $definition [, bool $add_empty = true ]] )
> >
> > ...
> >
> > **add_empty** - Добавляет в результат отсутствующие ключи со значением NULL.

Поскольку третий параметр вы не передаете, то он по дефолту `true`, отсюда и отсутствующий ключ со значением `null`.

Т.е. все, что вам надо - это передать третий параметр `false`:

```
$result = filter_var_array($input, $args, $add_empty=false);
```

**UPD**: третий параметр был добавлен в PHP 5.4, поэтому для PHP 5.3 это работать не будет, но можно использовать небольшой хак:

```
$result = filter_var_array($input + array_fill_keys(array_keys($args), null), $args);
```

Т.е. получаем ключи нашего фильтра, по этим ключам строим массив со значениями по умолчанию `null` и строим массив из исходного и полученного массива. На полученном массиве уже запускаем фильтрацию

Comment: Работает начиная с 5.4.0 ;)

Comment: @Visman, эмъ... я че-то не обратил внимание на 5.3 (

Comment: @Visman, добавил хак для 5.3, т.к. других вариантов, судя по всему, нет

Comment: Судя по вопросу, автору как раз null то и не нужен в результате.

Comment: @Visman, так `null` - это в `array_fill_keys(array_keys($args), null)`, а на выходе `filter_var_array` мы получаем дефолтное значение (что и хочет автор)

Comment: Да, чего-то я не то написал :)

Comment: @BOPOH, спасибо за хак. Буду пользоваться, пока не перейду на более новую версию php